# jQuery UI draggable prevents scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have draggable elements with full screen width listed vertically.

I am using a plugin called (jquery.ui.touch-punch) to enable jQuery draggable on mobile. But the problem is that the draggable elements prevent the user from scrolling the page.

```
$('#novieList .element .content').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    revert: function() {
        return $(this).position().left < 30;
    },
    containment: [ 0, 0, 75, 0 ],
    scope: 'element',
    scroll: false,
    delay: 300,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        return true;
    },
    start: function(event, ui) {
        // Prevent to drag the element after open it
        var left = $(this).position().left;
        return left == 0;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var left = $(this).position().left;
        if (left != 0) {
            $(this).offset({left: 75});
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Was as solution to this ever discovered? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: A solution might be to add up and down buttons to the interface that is fixed to the top and / or bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe commenting out `event.preventDefault()` in `jquery.ui.touch-punch.js` works any longer. I tried the same solution and found that jQuery UI `draggable` itself was blocking the default behavior of a vertical scroll -- even when the element is set to drag only along the x-axis.

The solution that worked for me was to measure any change in the cursor's vertical position and use `window.scrollBy` to manually scroll the window by the same amount:

```
var firstY = null;      
var lastY = null;
var currentY = null;
var vertScroll = false;
var initAdjustment = 0;

// record the initial position of the cursor on start of the touch
jqDraggableItem.on("touchstart", function(event) {
    lastY = currentY = firstY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
});

// fires whenever the cursor moves
jqDraggableItem.on("touchmove", function(event) {
    currentY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    var adjustment = lastY-currentY;

    // Mimic native vertical scrolling where scrolling only starts after the
    // cursor has moved up or down from its original position by ~30 pixels.
    if (vertScroll == false && Math.abs(currentY-firstY) > 30) {
        vertScroll = true;
        initAdjustment = currentY-firstY;
    }

    // only apply the adjustment if the user has met the threshold for vertical scrolling
    if (vertScroll == true) {
        window.scrollBy(0,adjustment + initAdjustment);
        lastY = currentY + adjustment;
    }

});

// when the user lifts their finger, they will again need to meet the 
// threshold before vertical scrolling starts.
jqDraggableItem.on("touchend", function(event) {
    vertScroll = false;
});
```

This will closely mimic native scrolling on a touch device.

Comment: This is a great solution, do you think it could be made any smoother? I tested it in Nokia Lumia, and the vertical scroll is not smooth, it is twitchy.

Comment: Yeah, it's not perfect, but it's probably as good as is possible with a JavaScript fix. I haven't tested on a Nokia Lumia, but I've tested on an S7, iPhone 6 and an iPod Touch (6th gen) -- the twitchiness was minimal on those devices, not noticeable unless you're looking for it. Those phones have Webkit-based browsers. Lumia is a Windows phone correct? 

You might try native smooth scrolling ( see https://blog.hospodarets.com/native_smooth_scrolling ). However, it doesn't work on all mobile browsers and I didn't really a notice in difference between enabled vs disabled.

Comment: I discovered one issue with newer versions of jQuery UI was that they're setting the CSS on draggable elements to `touch-action: none` which is preventing the default actions.  Trying changing that to `auto`, which is the default.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to that problem at [Scrolling jQuery UI touch punch](http://steampixel.de/enable-vertical-page-scrolling-jquery-ui-touch-punch/). You have to remove a `event.preventDefault()` in jquery.ui.touch-punch.js on line 38. So far I have only tested on Sony Xperia Z1 Compact, Android 5, Chrome, but it works very well in a project very similar to one named here.

Comment: The only issue is, the horizontal scrolling is not very smooth after the line has been removed. (Nokia Lumia)

Comment: This does work on my samsung S8+ BUT I am using drag and drop, so the list scrolls while im trying to move the item...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem regarding that I could scroll on mobile when my div was dragable, as the CSS of the Jquery UI had the following code set to none, so by reverting the changes by putting them on initial everything worked again!

.ui-draggable-handle {-ms-touch-action:initial!important;touch-action:initial!important}